# React Native app works in emulator but sync fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I can run my React Native app on Android Studio emulator and It works fine but I get this error when  Android Studio tries to sync project:

> **ERROR: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object**
>
> **The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69 Unable to
>   determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or
>   object**
>
> **line number 1**
>
> **index number 0**
>
> **Error: EPERM: operation notpermitted, scandir**
>
> 'D:/REACTNATIVE/OpalWeather/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'
>   at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:790:3)    at GlobSync._readdir
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)    at
>   GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)    at
>   GlobSync._readdir
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)    at
>   GlobSync._processReaddir
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)    at
>   GlobSync._process
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)    at
>   GlobSync._processGlobStar
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)    at
>   GlobSync._process
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)    at
>   GlobSync._processGlobStar
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)    at
>   GlobSync._process
>   (D:\REACTNATIVE\OpalWeather\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)

This problem appeared after I Generated the release APK and added signing config to my app's Gradle config .
[Publishing to Google Play Store](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

I am a **newbie** to Android Studio help me plz